# Guava cache asynchronous reload

Tags: java-8, guava

I have followed [guava cache documentation](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#refresh) and coded asynchronous cache reloading in my application. Additionally, during application start, I am loading the cache using `cache.put`. I am reloading it every 15 mins afterwards (provided there is an incoming request at/after 15 mins).  While debugging, I found that reload is called correctly and my application is not waiting for the updated graph from DB.

My Question is: Do I need to continue to override load method in my application? As described above, the initial loading of cache is done on application startup.

Below is my paraphrased code (about same as in documentation):

```
private LoadingCache<String, Graph> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .refreshAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .recordStats()           
        .build(new CacheLoader<String, Graph>() {
            @Override
            public Graph load(String key) {
                return getGraphFromDB(key);
            }

            public ListenableFuture<Graph> reload(final String key, Graph prev) {
                ListenableFutureTask<Graph> task = ListenableFutureTask.create(new Callable<Graph>() {
                    public Graph call() {
                        Graph graph = prev;
                        try {
                            graph = getGraphFromDB(key);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            logger.error("There was an exception when reloading the cache",e);                               
                        }
                        finally {
                            return graph;
                        }
                    }
                });
               executor.execute(task);
                return task;
            }
        });
```

Comment: If you remove it, the refresh will be called synchronously on a caller's thread. You might want to use `CacheLoader#asyncReloading(loader, executor)` which does your `reload` method for you. You could then write it as `CacheLoader.asyncReloading(CacheLoader.from(this:: getGraphFromDB), executor)`. (FYI - Caffeine's Java8 rewrite of Guava's cache does the refresh asynchronously by default).

Comment: @BenManes answered my question, so cool! I will implement your suggestions and get back on this thread. Many thanks!

Comment: @BenManes - I am unable to remove load method from my original implementation as this method is abstract in CacheLoader. Additionally I am able to implement ayncReloading, which is very concise, without  worrying about  implementing the load method myself.  However in my original method if  `getGraphFromDB` fails, I could set the value to previous value. I think I cannot do such thing with asyncReloading method. As a result if `getGraphFromDB` fails, on the next run the method is called again irrespective of refresh duration.  Please let me know your thoughts on this.  Sorry for wall of text.

Comment: I am yet to work on implementing Caffeine library

Comment: You're right, that is a difference with `asyncReloading`. You could decorate it with `Futures.catching` for the fallback, but that's probably more confusing combination than your original code. For `load()`, the `CacheLoader.from(Function)` is a handy adapter to support lambdas, had you been able to chain the calls succinctly.

Comment: Thank you, @BenManes!  This is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think its a good idea to use **asyncReloading**. In example we reload cache, containing PublicKeys every 1 minute. Also for debuging we use RemovalListener.

```
@Value("${security.jwks-cache-refresh-milliseconds:60000}") // 1 min
private Integer jwksCacheRefreshMilliseconds;

private Cache<String, PublicKey> jwksCache;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    TimeUnit timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;

    RemovalListener<String, PublicKey> removalListener = n -> {
        if (n.wasEvicted() && log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("jwksCache remove key : {}, reason : {}", n.getKey(), n.getCause().name());
        }
    };

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    jwksCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .refreshAfterWrite(Long.valueOf(jwksCacheRefreshMilliseconds), timeUnit)
            .removalListener(removalListener)
            .build(CacheLoader.asyncReloading(new CacheLoader<String, PublicKey>() {
                @Override
                public PublicKey load(String kid) throws Exception { // code to refresh key from jwks
                }
            }, scheduler));
}
```